# Flash error message not displaying the background colour in Flask. Why?

Tags: python, flask, error-messaging

Why is the **category `error` of Flask flash messages not working** for me?

```
flash('Error message', category='error')
```

I get the following invisible background instead of the red one. **What could be the reason?**

[image]

#### Other info

Using all the other known categories (`'success'`, `'info'`, `'warning'`) works pretty fine for me: I always get the correct message with the correct color:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "`danger`" category instead of "`error`". For example:

```
flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check your email and password', 'danger')
```